# Get full path of object in deeply nested object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

My source array looks like this:

```
    arr =[
  {
    "dimensionId": 1,
    "dimensionName": "dimensionName1",
    "components": [
      {
        "componentId": 1,
        "componentName": "componentName1",
        "indicators": [
          {
            "indicatorId": 1,
            "indicatorName": "indicatorName1"
          },
          {...}
        ]
      },
       {...}
    ]
  },
  {...}
];
```

When I am trying to search the most deeply nested object by  'indicatorId' using .filter and .map  , it return the object like this:

```
{
            "indicatorId": 1,
            "indicatorName": "indicatorName1"
}
```

What I need to do is keep track of the parent's properties as well when traversing through it's childrens. Desired output will be like this:

```
{
  "dimensionId": 1,
  "dimensionName": "dimensionName1",
  "componentId": 1,
  "componentName": "componentName2",
  "indicatorId": 1,
  "indicatorName": "indicatorName3"
}
```

Is there a way to do this recursively? 
 Edit: The id's are not unique throughout the array

Comment: please add your method also.

Comment: kindly mention how you are trying to search/traverse the given array?

Comment: what about, if you have more than one item in the nested arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through and return when found.

```js
arr =[
  {
    "dimensionId": 1,
    "dimensionName": "dimensionName1",
    "components": [
      {
        "componentId": 2,
        "componentName": "componentName2",
        "indicators": [
          {
            "indicatorId": 3,
            "indicatorName": "indicatorName3"
          },
     {
            "indicatorId": 3.1,
            "indicatorName": "indicatorName31"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
];

let out =  {}
arr.forEach(({dimensionId, dimensionName, components}) => {
 components.forEach(({indicators, componentId, componentName}) => {
  let found = indicators.find(({indicatorId}) => indicatorId === 3);
  if (found) {
   out = {dimensionId, dimensionName, componentId, componentName, ...found};
   return;
  }
 });
})

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add the index to the keys form the same arrays and return a new object for each nested array.

```js
function getFlat(array) {
    return array.reduce((r, o, i) => {
        Object
            .entries(o)
            .forEach(([k, v]) => Object.assign(r, Array.isArray(v)
                ? getFlat(v)
                : { [[k, i].join('_')]: v }
            ));
        return r;
    }, {});
}

var data = [{ dimensionId: 1, dimensionName: "dimensionName1", components: [{ componentId: 2, componentName: "componentName2", indicators: [{ indicatorId: 3, indicatorName: "indicatorName3" }, { indicatorId: 4, indicatorName: "indicatorName4" }] }, { componentId: 5, componentName: "componentName5", indicators: [{ indicatorId: 6, indicatorName: "indicatorName6" }, { indicatorId: 7, indicatorName: "indicatorName8" }] }] }];

console.log(getFlat(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This works , but only when the id's are unique throughout the 'arr' array. I have edited the array.